# Formatting a variable with another variable in Python

Tags: python, variables, formatting

Let's suppose I have a `for` loop. After each loop, I get a result that I want to store in a list.
I want to write something like this but it's not working:

```
for i in range(50):
    "result_%d" %i = result
```

Supposing that `result` is a list containing the results after each loop.
I want to do that in order to have a different list for each result, so I could be able to use them after the loop is finished.

Is there any way to do that?

Note: I thought about storing all the result lists in one big list. But won't that be heavy for the code? Noting that each result list has a size of 60.

Comment: *I thought about storing all the result arrays in one big array. But won't that be heavy for the code?* That is **exactly** how you'd do it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Depending on what you're using the data for, have a look at generators if there are _many_ items. My apologies ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought about storing all the result arrays in one big array. But won't that be heavy for the code?

In Python, everything is an object and names and list contents are just references to them. Creating new list objects containing references to existing values is *quite lightweight* really.

Don't try to create dynamic variables, just store your results in another list or a dictionary.

In this case that's as easy as:

```
results = []
for i in range(50):
    # do things
    results.append(result)
```

and `results` is then a list with 50 references to other list objects. That's no different from having 50 names referencing those 50 list objects, other than that it is *much* easier to address them now.